# Angular 9 - How to dynamicly display a part of a json depending on the route

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Hya everyone,
I am bit stuck, hope you will be able to help.
So, I would like to display only part of a Json depending on the route i'm on.
That Json could look like this :

```
[
  {
    "Key": "string",
    "Rule1": [
      {}
    ],
    "Rule2" : [
       {}    
    ]
}
]
```

so far, i've managed to display all the json within a directive that makes the json foldable.

So, when i click on a tab, i'd like to display only a part of that json. Example : I click the "key" tab, i got only what's in the "key" json property and so on...
I got 3 components : property, propertyTab and jsondisplay (not mentioning the directive).
In my property component, i put at the top of my template file :

```
<app-property-tab [property]="property"></app-property-tab>
```

Here is my propertytab ts file :

```
export class PropertyTabComponent implements OnInit {

    Key: string;
    @Input() property: Property;

  constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute, private blablaService: blablaService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params
    .subscribe(
      (params: Params) => {
        this.Key = params['Key'];
        this.property = this.blablaService.getProperty(this.Key);
      }
    );
  }

  onWatchRule1(){
      this.router.navigate([`blabla/${this.propertyKey}`])
  }

  onWatchRule2(){
    this.router.navigate([`blabla2/${this.propertyKey}`])
}

}
```

my template is simple as hell :

```
<li>
    <a (click)="Rule1()" >
        Rule1
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a(click)="onWatchRule2()">
        Rule2
    </a>
</li>
```

And my jsondisplay component :

```
export class JsonDisplayComponent implements OnInit {
    allData: any;
    name: any;
    Key: string;
    @Input() property: Property;

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private blablaService: blablaService,
    private jsonDisplayService: JsonDisplayService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
      this.route.params
      .subscribe(
          (params: Params) => {
            this.propertyKey = params['propertyKey'];
            this.property = this.blablaService.getProperty(this.Key);
          }
      );

      this.jsonDisplayService.getProperty(this.Key).subscribe((data: any) => {
          this.allData = data;
          this.name = data.Key;
          console.log(this.allData)
      })

  }

}
```

and the template :

```
<app-property-tab [property]="property"></app-property-tab>

<h3>{{ allData.propertyKey }}</h3>

<br/>
<div class="ats-form-group ml-4"  style="height: 100%; background-color: white;" *ngFor="let data of [allData]">
    <div [appJsonFormatter]="data.rule"></div>
</div>
```

So, what i would like to know is how to display only a part of that json depending on the tab we click on. Because the only thing i am able to do here is get all json or a part, but never dynamicly and never when i click on a tab. Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Find a way to get the selected tab. Subscribe on the event and change the content once you know what is selected.

Comment: Thank you. Actually, this is what i was thinking about. And subscribing to the event and changing the content will be, i guess, the pleasant part. But i dont know how to get the selected tab. You have an idea about it? Thanks mate.